# How do I access frames with NLTK + wordnet?

Tags: nlp, nltk, wordnet

I am accessing WordNet via NLTK. I want to group short phrases into semantic categories. I think that frames are words grouped into semantic categories. Ex: 'verb. buy' 'verb. sell' 'noun. cash' might be be grouped under the frame 'transaction'.

I see that I can get the [frame IDs from](http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html) a synset (altho the linked docs are a little wrong. The syntax for that is):

```
wn.synset('buy.v.01').frame_ids
[2, 8, 16]
```

I am confused about how to go from frame_id to frame. I would hope to do something like:

```
print wn.frames[2] 
buy, sell, shopping bag ...
```

How do I access frames with wordnet and NLTK?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import framenet (I used nltk version 3.0)

from nltk.corpus import framenet as fn
```

to load a frame use the `frame_by_id` function

```
frame = fn.frame_by_id(798)
```